# Export a pdf using FastReport.net and asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, fastreport

How is it possible to export a `pdf` using `FastReport.net` and `asp.net`?
I would like to export the File in a Controller. I tried it this way supported on the FastReport Website:

```
public FileResult GetFile()
        {
            WebReport webReport = new WebReport();

            // bind data
            System.Data.DataSet dataSet = new System.Data.DataSet();
            dataSet.ReadXml(report_path + "nwind.xml");
            webReport.Report.RegisterData(dataSet, "NorthWind");

            // load report
            webReport.ReportFile = this.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/report.frx");

            // prepare report
            webReport.Report.Prepare();

            // save file in stream
            Stream stream = new MemoryStream();
            webReport.Report.Export(new PDFExport(), stream);
            stream.Position = 0;

            // return stream in browser
            return File(stream, "application/zip", "report.pdf");
        }
```

but then the size of the `pdf` is always 0 bytes.

Does someone know a solution to my problem?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ok, now I found a solution. Just use the normal `Report` (not `WebReport`) and set `WebMode` to `true`. The other settings on pdf-Export are just for fun.

So, this will do the trick:

```
public FileResult GetFile(Dataset dataset1)
{
    FastReport.Utils.Config.WebMode = true;
    Report rep = new Report();
    rep.Load(Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + "App_Data/report.frx");    

    rep.RegisterData(dataset1);

    if (rep.Report.Prepare())
    {
        // Set PDF export props
        FastReport.Export.Pdf.PDFExport pdfExport = new FastReport.Export.Pdf.PDFExport();
        pdfExport.ShowProgress = false;
        pdfExport.Subject = "Subject";
        pdfExport.Title = "xxxxxxx";
        pdfExport.Compressed = true;
        pdfExport.AllowPrint = true;
        pdfExport.EmbeddingFonts = true;

        MemoryStream strm = new MemoryStream();
        rep.Report.Export(pdfExport, strm);
        rep.Dispose();
        pdfExport.Dispose();
        strm.Position = 0;

        // return stream in browser
        return File(strm, "application/pdf", "report.pdf");
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    } 
}
```

It's a pity that such code templates are wrong on the official site of the developer.

Answer (score 0):

Works for me in 2017.1

```
    public void GetFile()
    {
        SetReport();
        webReport.ExportPdf();
    }

    public void GetPrint()
    {
        SetReport();
        webReport.Prepare();
        webReport.PrintPdf();
    }
```